# Storing data in Excel using VB6.0 and then fetching the results to display in text box

Tags: sql, excel, vba, vb6

I am trying to make an application in VB6.0 using MS Excel as database. I have some textboxes on my VB Form to take input from user. I want to store those values in an Excel file. There will be another form where I want to retrieve the values from Excel and display it in textbox/labels.

Can I use SQL queries for inserting/retrieving the values while using Excel as database?

I just need a sample code for understanding the process. Rest I will try to manage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a poor idea.

While you can treat an Excel workbook as a data source via the Jet IISAM or ODBC Desktop Driver this is really meant for simple importing and exporting and has numerous limitations.

Save yourself some grief and just use Jet 4.0 to create and make use of MDB files.  No MS Access is required, Jet 4.0 comes preinstalled and has for a rather long time now.